# how to stop ajax procedure if new image is to small

Tags: javascript, ajax, image

I want to run an ajax procedure only if `new img` is `960 x 540`, but it seems there is a problem with getting the result of `img.onload`.

```
var src = localStorage.getItem('img');
img = new Image();
img.src = src;
var x = 0;
img.onload = function() {
    if (img.naturalWidth < 960 || img.naturalHeight < 540) {
        $('.cmenu').hide();
        console.log('CHOOSEN IMAGE IS TOO SMALL!');
        x = 1;
        return false; // doesn't work
    }
}
if (x == 1) {return false;}  // doesn't work.
$.ajax({...
```

How to stop `ajax` if image is smaller than `960 x 540` ?

Comment: Do it the other way round. Only start the ajax call if the size is correct - in the `onload` handler of the image.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `img.onload` will happen *after* the image is loaded, which will also happen *after* your `if( x == 1 )` check has already failed. 
To make it work I recommend putting the ajax call *inside* the `onload` function if the size is correct:

```
img.onload = function() {
    if (img.naturalWidth >= 960 || img.naturalHeight >= 540) {
        $.ajax({...
    }
    else{
        $('.cmenu').hide();
        console.log('CHOOSEN IMAGE IS TOO SMALL!');
    }
}
```